# ionic windows app signing issue

Tags: cordova, ionic2, windows-mobile, signtool

i need to deploy ionic windows app to enterprise store. so, after building windows when trying to sign with signtool getting error "0x8007000b" which means publisher name mismatch.

so, i have edited my appx10manifest.xml and rebuilt using

```
ionic build windows
```

same result.

what is understood is that when i am building windows via ionic cli, the publisher name of my enterprize certificate is getting **overwritten** with default cordova name "**CN=Apache Cordova Name**".

i didnt found where to change the **publisher name** value.
tried steps given at: https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/cordova-for-windows-build-options
didnt worked.

can someone help me?

Comment: later tried to sign using --buildConfig json,still the publisher id is correct.its following a regex for validating the publisher id.i am giving:(OID.1.x.x.xx.x.1.1=xx, CN=xxxx., OU=&quot;xx&quot;).**errmsg**:violates pattern constraint of '(CN|L|O|OU|E|C|S|STREET|T|G|I|SN|DC|SERIALNUMBER|Description|PostalCode|POBox|Phone|X21Address|dnQualifier|(OID\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*))+))=(([^,+="<>#;])+|".*")(, ((CN|L|O|OU|E|C|S|STREET|T|G|I|SN|DC|SERIALNUMBER|Description|PostalCode|POBox|Phone|X21Address|dnQualifier|(OID\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*))+))=(([^,+="<>#;])+|".*")))*'.

Answer (score 0):

You can change publisher id using Visual studio by following steps :

- Open (your project folder)\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.sln in Visual Studio
- Now Navigate to CordovaApp.Windows(Windows 8.1) and open the file **package.windows.appxmanifest** in Solution Explorer
- Goto **Packaging** (last tab) and click on **Choose Certificate...** button
- Now click on **Configure Certificate...** button
- From here you can choose your own certificate file for signing or you can create new test certificate.